# jQuery Slidertron Overflow

Tags: css, slideshow

I am using the [Slidertron lib](http://n33.co/files/jquery/zips/jquery.slidertron-1.1.zip) for a slideshow in one of my website. However, when I look at it depending of some resolutions, I can see the next slide in the current one, which should not happen.

CSS:

```
#slider {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%;position:relative;}
#slider .viewer {width:75%;height:400px;margin:0 auto;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid red;}
#slider .viewer .reel {display:none;height: 375px;}
#slider .slide {border:1px solid blue;}
#slider .viewer .reel .slide {position: relative;width:1100px;height:375px;}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="slider">
            <div class="indicator">
                <span>1</span>
                <span>2</span>
                <span>3</span>
                <span>4</span>
                <span>5</span>
            </div>
        <div class="viewer">
            <div class="reel">
                <div class="slide">
                    <img class="title" src="/Content/1.png" alt="" />
                    <p class="paragraph">Slide 1 text.</p>
                    <img class="image" src="/Content/2.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <img class="title" src="/Content/Img1.png" alt="" />
                    <p class="paragraph">Slide 2 text.</p>
                    <img class="image" src="/Content/Img2.png" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery (kind of irrelevant since this is working well):

```
        $(function () {
        $('#slider').slidertron({
            viewerSelector: '.viewer',
            reelSelector: '.viewer .reel',
            slidesSelector: '.viewer .reel .slide',
            indicatorSelector: '.indicator span',
            speed: 'slow',
            navPreviousSelector: '.previous',
            navNextSelector: '.next',
            advanceDelay: 40000
        });
    });
```

FYI, I added the two border just to see the delimitations of my divs.

Comment: You should post the relevant javascript as well as a link to this library you're using.

Comment: pls provide actual size of image in slide.

Comment: please post the slider js code

Comment: As you can see, slide is actually two images and a paragraph in a div (class slide) so there is no "size of image in slide".

Comment: then there should be one, else you will see two images if smaller then width:1100px;

I hope you are getting my point :)

Comment: Yes my bad. As you can see in the last CSS code line, the viewer is 1100px wide but so is my slide. That's why I don't get why I can see a small part of the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 25px difference between `.viewer` & `.reel` in your CSS!

For me, the best way jquery.slidertron works is when i strictly telling him image sizes with css.

```
/*slider*/
#slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
}
#slider .viewer {

    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider .viewer .reel {

    display: none;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
}
#slider .viewer .reel .slide {

    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 300px;
}
/*slider*/
```